# Django search in multiple field with multiple value

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I have a model which stores login logout time and date for users

```
class LoginLogout(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    login_time = models.TimeField()
    logout_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I need to search in this model by the field **date** and **username**. I have a form which takes **date_from**, **date_to** and **username** as input. Any field can be blank. If **username** is **blank** all results will be returned. Now what will be the queryset for achieving the desired queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to search in this model by the field date and username. I have a form which takes date_from, date_to and username as input.

You want to learn about [Django's query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/).

```python
events = LoginLogout.objects.filter(
        username=username,
        date__ge=date_from,
        date__le=date_to,
)
```

> Any field can be blank. If username is blank all results will be returned.

Those are special conditions, and should be represented as such in your code.

```python
filter_args = {}
if username:
    filter_args['username'] = username
    if date_from:
        filter_args['date__ge'] = date_from
    if date_to:
        filter_args['date__le'] = date_to
events = LoginLogout.objects.filter(**filter_args)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work :

```
if not username:
    return LoginLogout.objects.all()
else:
    return LoginLogout.objects.filter(date__gte=date_from,
                                      date__lte=date_to,
                                      username=username)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use many if else...

i just give you the query

```
# Case 1: All res:
res = LoginLogout.objects.all()
# Case 2: date_to is blank:
res = LoginLogout.objects.filter(login_time__gt = date_from)
# Case 3: date_from is blank
res = LoginLogout.Objects.filter(logout_time__lt = date_to)
# Case 4: all value
res = LoginLogout.Objects.filter( Q(username= username) & Q(login_...) & Q(logout_...)
# Or:
res = LoginLogout.Objects.filter(username= username, login_time__gt = ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was wishing to avoid many if else.

Comment: Sir, you can't give the hard work for User. You have to it in your side. And if you don't want too much if,else. Just set DEFAULT value for the data (like: logout_time = now, login_time = 1970....) it 's too ez way

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

if username or date_from or date_to:
    LoginLogout.objects.filter(
                               Q(username=username),
                               Q(date__gt='date_from'),
                               Q(date__lt='date_to')
                              )
else:
    LoginLogout.objects.all()
```